# Changed date format setting in WordPress now page won't load

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date, localhost

As far as I know the only thing I did was change the date format settings in settings -> general

From the first date format which is: June 13, 2016 F j, Y

to the custom mode asCustom date format:F j example: June 13

Now whenever I preview my site I get this error in chrome:

The localhost page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.

Any one have any idea to what could be going on? I have disabled all my plugins and the issue still remains.

Is there something that went wrong in the database? If so how can I change it?

Currently viewing my database with phpMyadmin but have no idea where the date settings are stored.

Comment: could you show us come code ?

Comment: @DarkMukke I really don't have code to show. I did the change through WP's admin panels.